# how find and sed commands can be used to apppend to matched pattern recursively

Tags: linux, sed, find, pattern-matching

I am trying to append a string to a pattern, if matched, using `find` and `sed` commands, recursively (on web root).

I have tried the following, but those did not work:

1. For appending:

   ```
   find . -name \*.php -exec sed -i "s,alt=\".*\"  \/\>,& style=\"border:1px solid silver\",g" {} \;
   ```
2. For deleting next line found after match:

   ```
   find . -name \*.php -exec sed -e '/<article itemscope itemtype=\"http:\/\/schema.org\/TechArticle\"\>/{N;d}' {} \;
   ```

What shall be the commands?

Comment: Please revise the formatting, some backslashes might be redundant.

Comment: Thanks. Problem 2 (For deleting next line found after match) worked this way:

find . -name \*.php -exec sed -i '/<article itemscope itemtype="http:\/\/schema.org\/TechArticle">/{n;N;d}' {} \;